# Opposite of SetFocus

Tags: vba, ms-access

MSAccess VBA:
Assume, in an arbitrary form, the focus is set to MyControl on that form.
How to "unset" the focus without giving the focus to another control?

I'm lokking for a code like 
`MyControl.UnsetFocus`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your circumstance, you probably want to just set focus back to the parent form. This meets the conditions of unsetting focus without giving another control focus, and tabbing or clicking will activate the focus / tab-navigation again from that form.

Here's an example:

```
Forms![MyForm].SetFocus
```

Note that per the documentation for `SetFocus`, if you attempt to `SetFocus` to a Form with child controls that have `Enabled` set, this will cause focus to automatically bounce to the first eligible child control per the documentation.

[Form.SetFocus method (Access) @ Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.setfocus)

Answer (score 0):

The option to give focus to the parent form does work as proposed by meklarian

Alternatively, I recently had to do something similar but I wanted to update a textbox value and simply go back to whatever had focus before. This is another case where something like an "unsetfocus" would be awesome, but unfortunately doesn't exist.

Should you need to do something like this, the following works well

```
Screen.PreviousControl.SetFocus
```